# Videochat without using webrtc?

Tags: webrtc, videochat, video-codecs

I say "without" using webrtc because, webrtc currently supports very few codecs, I would like to make a videochat using a custom or experimental codecs, so I'm starting with implementing basic udp websockets, but how do I implement something like SDP? Since the ip of the clients will keep changing, how do I maintain connection? Can anyone point me to a decent way of implementing this?

Comment: There is no justification to ditch WebRTC for lack of codecs. This framework is flexible enough for you to add any experimental codecs you want. If you want to run your videochat in a browser, you have an even higher threshold to pass.

Comment: So pick some other protocol. There are twenty years of media transfer protocols before WebRTC.